# bundling error on react native app (ambigous resolution)

Tags: react-native, responsive

```
Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  0.0% (0/1), failed.
error: bundling failed: ambiguous resolution: module `C:\Users\mtlok\Desktop\RN2\pep_beta\index.js` tries to require `react-native`, but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them:

  * `C:\Users\mtlok\Desktop\RN2\pep_beta\node_modules\react-native-responsive-dimensions\node_modules\react-native\package.json`
  * `C:\Users\mtlok\Desktop\RN2\pep_beta\node_modules\react-native\package.json`
```

Im getting this error when bundling react-native app.

This issue may be caused by the react-native-responsive-dimensions package

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-responsive-dimensions",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Resposive fontSize, height and width for your react-native components.",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "test": "exit 0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "responsive",
    "responsive-height",
    "responsive-width",
    "responsive-font-size",
    "fontSize",
    "responsive-dimensions"
  ],
  "author": "DaniAkash <s.daniakash@gmail.com> (https://github.com/DaniAkash)",
  "repository": "DaniAkash/react-native-responsive-dimensions",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "x"
  }
}
```

Also, there is a node_modules folder located inside node_modules/react-native-responsive-dimensions.

Is there a quick fix?

Comment: remove the package and re-install. There was an update on the package 4 hours ago. fixed the mistake on package.json file which `dependencies` should be `peerDependencies`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this command. maybe it's because of cache.

```
yarn start -- --reset-cache
```

or

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

if it doesn't work you can try `react-native-git-upgrade` or you can just delete node_modules folder then run `npm install`,`react-native upgrade` ande `react-native-link`

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall react-native-responsive-dimensions package first.

```
npm uninstall react-native-responsive-dimensions --save
```

And then

```
yarn start -- --reset-cache or npm start -- --reset-cache
react-native run-android or react-native run-ios
```